# Override Windows 8 login

Tags: windows-8, authentication, microsoft-metro

Is there a way to prgrammatically change/access/override the Windows 8 login feature? I have an idea for an alternative to a picture password I want to try and implement.

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/5/F3536898-FF3C-4548-8418-08D79555A0DB/Credential%20Provider%20Framework%20Changes%20in%20Windows%208.docx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776042(v=vs.85).aspx